# env variable couldn't able to set in powershell / pwsh terminal

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables, powershell-core

Here I'm using webdriver.io and want to set enviromental variable mode to "offline" .This command is working for linux and mac . But for the powershell / pwsh in windows its not working .

`"test:offline": "env status=offline wdio run ./wdio.runner.conf.ts",`

`npm run test:offline`

I'm expected to  the command mentioned should work for all platform and terminal .

Answer (score 0):

> I'm expected to the command mentioned should work for all platform and
> terminal.

Why would you expect that? Linux and macOS are flavors of Unix. Windows is not based on Unix and has a different set of commands and behaviors. In particular, Windows has no `env` command. There is probably something equivalent but `env var=val program` won't work on Windows.